# Will the usage of stored procedures make my work more complex, or will it be too time or performance consuming to use?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I am currently in a project for college to write a program to store information about other companies they interact with (like contact information, delivery information etc.) and what is in their general stock at any point of time (Such as the Brand, Model, Amount of the item in stock, Manufacturer/Supplier information etc.) and customer information.

I am wondering if I must use a huge amount of stored procedures to take advantage of error handling and transactions using T-SQL, or would it be faster to just use the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` Class to run plain queries? I have some sample code that I have worked out to store information on a customer in a database using T-SQL and C#, which wasn't a problem. Our task states that we will be judged by complexity and performance of our program.

This is the stored procedure I used:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddCustomers @Name varchar(30), @Surname varchar(30), @Addressline1 varchar(300),@Addressline2 varchar(300),@Telephone varchar(12),@CellPhone varchar(12),@Email Varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TrnAddCustomer;
        INSERT INTO [TCTdb].[dbo].[Customers]
                   ([Name]
                   ,[Surname]
                   ,[Addressline1]
                   ,[Addressline2]
                   ,[Telephone]
                   ,[Cellphone]
                   ,[Email])
             VALUES
                   (@Name
                   ,@Surname
                   ,@Addressline1
                   ,@Addressline2
                   ,@Telephone
                   ,@CellPhone
                   ,@Email)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION TrnAddCustomer;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TrnAddCustomer;

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,
               @ErrorSeverity,
               @ErrorState
               );
END CATCH
GO
```

These are the Code Snippets I used to call the stored procedure:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SQLCommands comm = new SQLCommands(); //Custom Class containing method below.
        comm.AddCustomer(tbName.Text, tbSurname.Text, tbAddressline1.Text, tbAddressline2.Text, tbPhoneNumber.Text, tbCellphoneNumber.Text, tbEmail.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Success! Note, if the data you inserted was too long, it may have been subjected to truncation to fit in the Database.", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        tbName.Text = tbSurname.Text = tbPhoneNumber.Text = tbCellphoneNumber.Text = tbAddressline2.Text = tbAddressline1.Text = tbEmail.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It appears something has gone wrong. Please contact the Supervisor if this problem keeps reoccurring", "Unknown Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
}
```

AND

```
 public void AddCustomer(params string[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            comm = new SqlCommand("UspAddCustomers", conn); // Stored Procedure
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", parameters[0]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", parameters[1]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addressline1", parameters[2]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addressline2", parameters[3]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", parameters[4]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellPhone", parameters[5]);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", parameters[6]);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

**The Question:**
So to revise my question, I was about to use this type of code to handle all CRUD for my tables in my database. I am worried though that this may chew the performance of my program, because there is a lot of tables involved. Is it advisable to carry on like this, or should I consider using simpler methods for manipulating data in my database?

**The reason why I thought of using this method was to enhance complexity**

Comment: Does your task require more complexity or less?

Comment: They want it to be as complex as it can be, but also have good performance. I literally have 2 days to finish this

Comment: There are 6 tables in my database which will need operations as in my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using C#, have you considered using LINQ-to-SQL?  It's a pretty sophisticated framework built into .NET, but very easy to use and eliminates the need for a good deal of framework code in the lower levels of your code.  It could save you a good deal of time, but maybe only if you have time to familiarize yourself with LINQ-to-SQL.  I have used it in an environment where we don't use stored procedures (the queries and updates are effectively generated by LINQ-to-SQL based on LINQ queries and methods written in the code), but I believe you can also tell it to use stored procedures.

I'm not sure how they're scoring complexity.  If it's based on how much code *you* write, then this might be a step in the wrong direction, since I think you would write much less code.  But overall, I think more complexity/sophistication would be involved in a LINQ-to-SQL solution because it translates LINQ queries into SQL queries internally, and can be ported to other database platforms as a result.

Comment: I have considered it yes, but based on my lesser amount of experience in it (we only covered this in a 1 day module, where we spent months in SQL server, moving on to Stored procs now) I decided to use the stored procs in-stead. So I researched how they worked and thought it a good idea...before I started doubting. I think I'm taking your response as the answer. I will look into this immediately.

Comment: I also wasn't worried by the amount of code I would write. I was worried it may cease performance, since it seemed like quite a lot

Comment: Linq to SQL is an ORM you should really read up about it and study the subject it would give you excellent material for the research side of your project

Comment: In my experience, performance of LINQ-to-SQL is pretty good for the simple batch retrieve and singleton updates that are performed most frequently in general.  If you have to update a batch of records, it performs a round-trip for every record, though.  But since that's rare, I used LINQ-to-SQL for most operations, and then used SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy to insert batches of records when performance was a concern (one case).  You do sometimes have to be careful in more complex queries -- understand which pieces can be done within the SQL statement and which would retrieve records to the client.

Answer (score 1):

whilst not really an answer to the question, one thing is for certain, your method:

```
 public void AddCustomer(params string[] parameters)
```

is a terrible idea.  How will you know which parameter to pass where?  you should declare this method with the details it needs to populate the table:

```
 public void AddCustomer(string fisrtName, string lastName, string addressLine1, string addressLine2, string telephone, string cellphone, string emailAddress)
```

or even better encapsulate the address in an `Address` class, the phone details in a `PhoneDetails` class and haver a `Customer` class which has an `Address` and a `PhoneDetails` and the first and last name and then pass this to your method.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, Ill wait and see if more solutions pop up. I admit the (params string[] parameters) was my lazy side jumping in, because I am time-pressed. I have however a list of which parameter that fits where, though I know its inadvisable to construct methods like that.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @nawfal, no its not really an answer to the question, but was too long for a comment, and was, I felt, generally helpful.

Comment: hmm... +1 = 0 ;). Kindly edit it so that I can cancel my vote

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using an object relational mapper such as NHibernate (it might get you extra brownie points)

Comment: lol, I have no idea what you just said. brownie points..good one :)

Comment: The entire project is out of 280 points. This program is merely worth 105 / 280. The rest of the points consist of documentation and research, GUI planning and interviews.

Comment: ORMs map objects from one type to another, so you could map business objects to a database. Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping and this http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET

Answer (score 0):

I would always prefer plain queries over stored procs. Stored procs are hard to debug considering we dont see the actual query behind it from the IDE. Since you would want to finish it off quickly, to simply make debugging easier, you should be going for plain queries. If the application would be given maintenance and support later on in large scale, stored proc must be better. But in your case I feel standard application querying would be better.

Comment: Standard application querying was taught to us last year (when I was a first-year) student. To be honest, I was hoping to impress my teacher and learn something out of the experience using Stored Procs, as we are yet to learn how they work. We covered ground like Indexing, Security, Aggregates, but we are yet to go to stored procedures and functions (Next week really) before moving on to reporting using crystalreports. I guess you are right. I might have to tune this down a little for debugging purposes, and the small scale of the app.